How to fix slicer position in excel during cell scrolling in any direction
In excel when i scroll cell in any direction that time slicer position also be scroll in cell direction but i want to fix slicer position for any scrolling it remain fix at their position
I try to fix slicer position and size but remain it position change when i scroll cell
